# Background mp3 download on iOS 14 in a swift ui app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, urlsession

I'm creating a swift UI radio streaming app that has a library of past episodes that can be downloaded. I would like users to be able to begin a download and then lock the screen. Currently this suspends the download(s) in progress. My download function :

```swift
func downloadFile(withUrl url: URL, andFilePath filePath: URL) {
        URLSession.shared
            .downloadTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .retry(4)
            .map(\.0)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [self] _ in
                      downloading = false
                      downloaded = true
                  },
                  receiveValue: { data in
                      do {
                          self.downloading = true
                          try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: data.path,
                                                           toPath: filePath.path)
                      } catch {
                          self.downloaded = false
                          print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                          print("an error happened while downloading or saving the file")
                      }
                  })
            .store(in: &networkSubscription)
    }
```

Where `.downloadTaskPublisher(for: url)` is :

```swift
import Combine
import Foundation

public extension URLSession {
    /// Returns a publisher that wraps a URL session download task for a given
    /// URL.
    ///
    /// - Parameter url: The URL for which to create a download task.
    /// - Returns: A publisher that wraps a download task for the URL.
    func downloadTaskPublisher(for url: URL) -> DownloadTaskPublisher {
        DownloadTaskPublisher(session: self, request: URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    /// Returns a publisher that wraps a URL session download task for a given
    /// URL request.
    ///
    /// - Parameter request: The URL request for which to create a download task.
    /// - Returns: A publisher that wraps a download task for the URL request.
    func downloadTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> DownloadTaskPublisher {
        DownloadTaskPublisher(session: self, request: request)
    }
}

public struct DownloadTaskPublisher {
    fileprivate let session: URLSession
    fileprivate let request: URLRequest
}

extension DownloadTaskPublisher: Publisher {
    public typealias Output = (URL, URLResponse)
    public typealias Failure = Error

    public func receive<Subscriber>(subscriber: Subscriber)
        where
        Subscriber: Combine.Subscriber,
        Subscriber.Failure == Failure,
        Subscriber.Input == Output
    {
        let subscription = Subscription(subscriber: subscriber, session: session, request: request)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
}

private extension DownloadTaskPublisher {
    final class Subscription {
        private let downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask

        init<Subscriber>(subscriber: Subscriber, session: URLSession, request: URLRequest)
            where
            Subscriber: Combine.Subscriber,
            Subscriber.Input == Output,
            Subscriber.Failure == Failure
        {
            downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: request, completionHandler: { url, response, error in

                guard let url = url, let response = response else {
                    subscriber.receive(completion: .failure(error!))
                    return
                }

                _ = subscriber.receive((url, response))
                subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
            })
        }
    }
}

extension DownloadTaskPublisher.Subscription: Subscription {
    fileprivate func request(_: Subscribers.Demand) {
        downloadTask.resume()
    }

    fileprivate func cancel() {
        downloadTask.cancel()
    }
}
```

This download function writes the episode to disk but is canceled when the app is suspended.

I would like to write something like

```swift
func downloadFile(withUrl url: URL, andFilePath filePath: URL) {
        URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "background.download.session"))
            .downloadTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .retry(4)
            .map(\.0)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [self] _ in
                      downloading = false
                      downloaded = true
                  },
                  receiveValue: { data in
                      do {
                          self.downloading = true
                          try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: data.path,
                                                           toPath: filePath.path)
                      } catch {
                          self.downloaded = false
                          print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                          print("an error happened while downloading or saving the file")
                      }
                  })
            .store(in: &networkSubscription)
    }
```

However, this throws a runtime exception: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead.' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

I would like to download files in the background using combine idioms and avoid have to attach an `AppDelegate` to my `@main struct: App`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the error throws by the compiler, I pretty sure you need to activate the Background Modes like this :
[image]

I did found a detailed tutorial by [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) that follows almost exactly your use case. Maybe it can help you to dig even deeper on this feature

Comment: I think the link you mean is https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-016 Unfortunately this uses the ```AppDelegate``` pattern that I am trying to avoid, ultimately this is an option, my question specifically is asking if there is a way to do this using the swift ui ```App``` and ```Combine``` idioms.

Comment: You have to use the AppDelegate because as it is now, there no over way to my knowledge to make background tasks works. But that's really easy to access AppDelegate functions in SwiftUI. Take a look at this tutorial : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app 

Comment: Once you have integrated the AppDelegate in your SwiftUI app lifecycle, it will be really easy to setup as it is with UIKit App. 